# How to select Country with SEPA direct debit (short tutorial)

Tags: civisepa

If you want to set a SEPA creditor you will need to define a country. 
As said in the help menu you have to go to Administer>Localization>Language and Localization.

[image]

Not only you have to set a default country

[image]

but you also need to make available your country (which sounds half logical)

[image]

Now you can select your favorite country ;-)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It looks useful but it doesn't look like a question. It would be better to put it into a Q&A format and answer your own question. See: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/